# Teradata 13: CASE statement in Join

Tags: teradata

Is CASE statement allowed in join? Is there a good way to accomplish the task here? My real query has some other left join.

I would like to join T1 and T2 in this condition:
1. when T1.sub_service is not null, then join with T2.type
2. when T1.sub_service is null, then use T1.service to join with T2.type

```
SELECT T1.service, T1.sub_service, T2.type 
FROM      TABLE1 T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2
ON T2.type LIKE
   CASE WHEN T1.sub_service IS NULL THEN T1.service
        WHEN T1.sub_service IS NOT NULL THEN T1.sub_service
   END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply replace the **LIKE** with **=**:

```
ON T2.type = 
   CASE WHEN T1.sub_service IS NULL THEN T1.service
        WHEN T1.sub_service IS NOT NULL THEN T1.sub_service
   END
```

But you can further simplify this to a COALESCE:

```
ON T2.type = COALESCE(T1.sub_service, T1.service)
```

Comment: Can I use "like" instead of "=" because there are some type I need to use "like" in order to get match some types.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you show some examples what you actually try to do?

Comment: I changed the query to "ON COALESCE(T1.sub_service, T1.service) LIKE T2.type" and it works.  I get the right result.  Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: If this is your actual condition it's the same as using equality (unless there are some trailing blanks), but might result in a bad plan.

Comment: Teradata doesn't ignore trailing blanks in a join?

Comment: Trailing blanks are ignored for a comparison using </=/>, but LIKE has different semantics. **'a' LIKE 'a '** returns false, but **'a' = 'a ' returns** true (and this is Standard SQL behaviour)

Comment: I would simplify the whole `ON` clause, to: `ON T1.sub_service IS NULL AND T2.type LIKE T1.service OR T2.Type LIKE T1.sub_service`